# how to bind a dynamic array model property to a agilityjs object's view

Tags: agility.js

I am using agilityjs as a client side mvc framework. I have a situation where I have a div element that is supposed to show a list of merchants that is retrieved from the server side and put as a model on the client side.

```
var merchants = //retrieve merchants from server as json array;
var merchantsWrapper = $$({'merchants':merchants},'<div id="merchants-wrapper"></div>');
```

Now I need a way to bind the `merchants` model property to be bound to the `merchants-wrapper div` where this div should display all the merchants. Each merchant is displayed in a particular layout defined in another prototype `merchant agility object` as:

```
var merchantProto = $$({//model props}, '<div>rendering layout</div>');
```

I want a mechanism by which the `merchants array` should get two way bound to the `merchants-wrapper div` and each merchant should render according to the `merchant prootype`, and in case the `merchants` property gets changed by sorting or filtering the view should get updated accordingly.

I have an idea that I can render it once on `create` event and do the same on `change:merchants` event, but I dont want to create new merchant objects, so either there should be a way to clear the contents of the `merchants-wrapper` div and then append the new merchants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I tried this and it worked for me.....

```
var merchants = //retrieve merchants from server as json array;
var merchantsWrapper = $$({'merchants':merchants},'<div id="merchants-wrapper"></div>',
    {
      'create':function(){
           var merchnts = [];
           for (each merchant in merchants){  //its pseudocode plz dnt mind the syntax
              var merchnt = $$(merchantProto,{//model props});
              merchnts.push(merchnt); 
           }
           this.model.set({'merchants':merchnts});
       },

       'change:merchants':function(){
           this.view.$("#merchants-wrapper").html("");
           for(each merchant in this.model.get('merchants')){
               this.append(merchant);
           }  
       }
);
```

I hope it might help others :)

Comment: I think that rather than going to the jQuery layer and directly removing the HTML on each change in `merchants` with the line `this.view.$("#merchants-wrapper").html("");`, you would be better off calling `this.empty()`.  Otherwise you may have a memory problem as the `merchant` Agility objects are created on every `change` event but never properly destroyed.